# Do browsers really send chunk trailers in their requests?

Tags: http, browser, header, chunked-encoding

In [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), there's [chapter 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.4):

> When a message includes a message body encoded with the chunked
> transfer coding and the sender desires to send metadata in the form
> of trailer fields at the end of the message, the sender SHOULD
> generate a Trailer header field before the message body to indicate
> which fields will be present in the trailers.  This allows the
> recipient to prepare for receipt of that metadata before it starts
> processing the body, which is useful if the message is being streamed
> and the recipient wishes to confirm an integrity check on the fly.

> ```
> Trailer = 1#field-name
> ```

This reads to me like the `Trailer` header could be generated by a server as well as by a client.

If I were implementing HTTP in a server that gets accessed by regular clients (i.e. browsers): **is there a real need to be prepared to receive trailing headers?** Are there any browsers that are really using this? Or is this something I *could* implement with a custom client but is not used by regular clients in the real world?